# Writing unit tests with Random

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I'm trying to test the behaviour of a method to generate a URL with a few parameters. The method makes use of a helper method which in turn makes use of `new Random().nextDouble()`.

```
private static String generateChecksum() {
    return "s" + new Double(Math.floor(Instant.now().getEpochSecond() / 10800000)).longValue() % 10 +
            new Double(Math.floor(10000000000000L * new Random().nextDouble())).longValue();
}
```

My goal for this particular test is to ensure the output of the method matches what I expect. My issue is I can't predict the result of `Random.nextDouble()`.

I read you can mock the results and I thought that overriding every instance of that method. I found out I couldn't do that but also that [I shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24576921/how-to-globally-mock-method-call-in-mockito), but instead I should re-write my code to fit my test.

How do I rewrite it? Do I pass the checksum into the method pre-generated along with the parameters so my flow goes from:

```
1. Main()
2. generateUrl(params)
2a. generateChecksum() // for use in generateUrl
3. return URL
```

to

```
1. Main()
2. generateChecksum()
3. generateUrl(params, checksum)
4. return URL
```

Or am I missing something? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In order to make such code testable, you there are two things that matter:

- you want to somehow fake the system clock. This [article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=234) tells you how you can do that in Java 8 by using the Clock class
- when random comes in, simply use a **[seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12458383/java-random-numbers-using-a-seed)**. Which allows you to "predict" the random numbers that will come up in your production code.

In other words: you can control the time *and* the random number that your production code will see!

Alternatively, simple *delegate* the whole computation into something that you can easily mock, such as:

```
public class CheckSumGenerator {

  public String generate(...) { ...
```

Now, you can easily mock that class, and have it return whatever you want it to return. Without thinking about clocks or random numbers.

But keep in mind: setting a seed might still be a good idea, and ideally, you might want to use a *secure* random number as seed.

Comment: I wouldn't fake the system clock. Ultimately the problem is that the static methods calls make the class untestable. You solve that by pulling out the static method calls.

Comment: @Michael Enhanced my answer around that idea.

Comment: The Clock usage (as alternative to change the system clock) requires some changes but is fine. And for `new Random(42)` the same holds. In fact unit-tests are the intended use-cases for those constructs. Good you added the change for mocking the use of Clock and Random.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to add a new parameter holding that random number to your methods:

```
private static String generateChecksum(double r) {
    return "s" + new Double(Math.floor(Instant.now().getEpochSecond() / 10800000)).longValue() % 10 +
            new Double(Math.floor(10000000000000L * r)).longValue();
}

static String generateUrl(double r) {
    // call generateChecksum(r)
}

public static String generateUrl() {
    // trivial
    return generateUrl(new Random().nextDouble());
}
```

Now you can just test `generateUrl(double r)` method easily. You don't need to test `generateUrl()` method because it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test something when the results are not known ahead of time.

You need to inject the source of randomness as a dependency so that you can supply constants in your tests.

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Supplier<Double> randomNumberGenerator;

    public MyClass(Supplier<Double> randomNumberGenerator) {
        this.randomNumberGenerator = randomNumberGenerator;
    }

    private String generateChecksum() {
        //... randomNumberGenerator.get();
    }
}
```

In your application code, create the object like this:

```
new MyClass(() -> new Random().nextDouble());
```

In your test, create it like this, for example:

```
new MyClass(() -> 10.0);
```

You can do the same thing with the timestamp. `Supplier<Instant>`, `Instant::now`, `() -> Instant.ofEpochSecond(123456)`

Answer (score 0):

While it is true that you do not know the *exact* output of the method using a random component, I don't think it is necessary to test for any exact output, but rather for the correct format of the output, i.e., validate that the output is *a* valid URL instead of a specific instance where you eliminate the randomness.

Of course the output might pass this check by chance, but by picking a specific seed you essentially run into the same problem.